# Generate all possible combinations of a set of numbers in excel

Tags: excel, math, numbers, combinatorics

How can I generate all possible combinations, in Excel, by using only 3, 6 and 9 in a 5 digit number? Naturally digits can repeat.

I am trying to learn more about EXCEL and this is something I cannot figure out - how to generate all possible combinations and see them instead of just having a number of possibilities.

I've looked through many forums, there's nothing I can use...

http://planetcalc.com/3756/?license=1 - This link is to an online generator, however there must be a mistake in its code since it doesn't show 5 digit numbers.

Comment: Could you please amend the question so it's stand-alone? i.e. no link to the generator example. Also, could you give an example? I can't figure out what your first sentence means.

Comment: You write "This link is to an online generator, however there must be a mistake in its code since it doesn't show 5 digit numbers." If you input 5 in the field after "Combination size m:" you get one single combination. Apparently the online generator you're linking does not allow repeated digits. You need to do some more research before posting a question on SO, see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Just loop over the selections:

```
Sub Maja()
  Dim K As Long
  K = 1
  vals = Array("3", "6", "9")
  For Each a In vals
    For Each b In vals
      For Each c In vals
        For Each d In vals
          For Each e In vals
            Cells(K, 1) = a & b & c & d & e
            K = K + 1
          Next e
        Next d
      Next c
    Next b
  Next a
  MsgBox K
End Sub
```

A snap of the top of the list:

[image]

**NOTE:**

Technically, you would call these **permutations** rather than **combinations** because values like *33363* and *33336* both appear in the list as they represent different numerical values.